# Can't get sympy to solve a hard equation (Python, sympy)

Tags: python, sympy, calculation

I am trying to solve a difficult equation with sympy in Python. The problem is that is does find an answer and hangs instead.

I'm using the following code to get an answer:

```py
from numpy import pi, e
from sympy import symbols, solve, sin, cos, sqrt, log, atan, re

I_p   = 50000
mu_0  = 4*pi*10**-7
m_s   = 2.402
n_cond= 2
f     = 50
a_s   = 0.1
d     = 0.03624
kappa = 1.999999999
kappa = max(1.1, kappa)
tau = (-2*pi*f/3  *  log((kappa-1.02)/0.98))**-1
gamma = atan(2*pi*f*tau)
v1 = f/(sin(pi/n_cond)) * sqrt((a_s-d)*m_s/(mu_0/(2*pi) * (I_p/n_cond)**2 * (n_cond-1)/a_s))
v2_sym    = symbols('v2_sym', real=True, rational=False)
T_pi      = v1/(f*sqrt(v2_sym))
v2_eval   = fun_v2(pi, f, T_pi, gamma, tau)
v2        = solve(f*T_pi*sqrt(v2_eval)-v1)
```

With fun_v2() defined as:

```py
def fun_v2(pi, f, T_pi, gamma):
    """See A7 for the formula for v2 in NEN-EN-IEC 60865-1:2012"""
    part1 = 1 - (sin(4*pi*f*T_pi-2*gamma)+sin(2*gamma))/(4*pi*f*T_pi)
    part2 = f*tau/(f*T_pi)*(1-e**-(2*f*T_pi/(f*tau)))*(sin(gamma))**2
    part3 = 8*pi*f*tau*sin(gamma)/(1+(2*pi*f*tau)**2)
    part4 = 2*pi*f*tau*cos(2*pi*f*T_pi-gamma)/(2*pi*f*T_pi)
    part5 =            sin(2*pi*f*T_pi-gamma)/(2*pi*f*T_pi)
    part6 = e**(-f*T_pi/(f*tau))
    part7 = (sin(gamma)-2*pi*f*tau*cos(gamma))/(2*pi*f*T_pi)
    v2    = part1 + part2 - part3 * ((part4 + part5) * part6 + part7)
```

The actual problem that I am trying to solve is given in [this document](https://community.ptc.com/t5/Mathcad/Root-error-interval-signs/td-p/587831?attachment-id=68045), which I found online. So basically I need to have a function that gives the value of v2, with v1 and kappa as inputs.

Does anyone know why this problem occurs?

Comment: please, edit the question and add the missing information. Right now I'm getting `f` is not defined.

Comment: The code is incomplete so it is not clear exactly what equation you are trying to solve but it looks like something that would be very unlikely to have an analytic solution.

Comment: f = 50

I copied just part of the code, so I forgot to mention that.

Comment: there are at least two more variables that are undefined.... please edit the question with everything needed to run the example

Comment: The question is now updated with the missing variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to solve `v2_eval` for `v2`. Since `v2` is the only free symbols of the expression, you are looking for a numerical result, hence sympy's `solve` is not the right tool for this job. SymPy's `nsolve` allows us to find a numerical solution, but it requires an initial guess. Since this is a 1D case, to find a good initial guess we can plot the expression:

```py
from sympy import plot, nsolve
expr = f*T_pi*sqrt(v2_eval)-v1
plot(expr, (v2_sym, 0, 10))
```

[image]

From the picture we can see that there is a root somewhere around 2: this is our initial guess. Finally:

```py
nsolve(expr, v2_sym, 2)
# out: 1.89685608221466
```

A final note: you mixed numpy and sympy to create the expression. You were lucky, as usually it creates problems. Always use sympy to create symbolic expression (use sympy's `E` for the exponential number, and sympy's `pi`).